# NSDateComponents setWeek - Find this week

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

Is it possible to find the current week of the year using NSDateComponents and setWeek: ? As setWeek uses a number form 1 - 52 every week in the year, how can I find the number representing this week?

Comment: you mean the week of the current date, right?

Comment: Yep. So just a number, so 1 being the first week of the year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think the solution is simple, you create a NSDateComponents of the current date and you get the week.

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags
                                                   fromDate:[NSDate date] // for current date
                                                    options:0];

    NSUInteger week = [dateComponents week];  // here is your week
```

Comment: Ahh! I see, well I just found out, before looking back here, I could do it this way:

Comment: NSDateFormatter *weekFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [weekFormatter setDateFormat:@"w"];
 NSString *weekDateString = [weekFormatter stringFromDate:curDate];
 [weekFormatter release];

Comment: Note that the correct form is NSCalendar components: fromDate:, ie. skip the options:!